# how to include more than one c# class into the same listview uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, template10

**The Structure**

I'm creating a UWP app, and ASP WebService to access a SQL Server dbase. Both UWP and WebService have identical Models of 7 base classes that are correspond to the tables of the database.

**The Issue**

The biggest issue is I'm a newbie dev, so my lack of insight is the Real Issue, but you cant solve that monumental task just yet.. The solvable issue is, How do I get more than one set of values inside of my ListView from multiple base classes. In my example, I'm referencing public `List<Device> Devices { get; private set; } = new List<Device>();` but I don't know how to reference more than one class in the list.. What I would like to do is List some values from Device and others from Location.

**The Code**

DisplayDevices.xaml

```
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Devices}"
                          SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.deviceList_SelectionChanged}"
                           x:Name="deviceList" Margin="50,0,0,50"
                           Header="{x:Bind ViewModel.RouterName}"
                           RelativePanel.RightOf="EditViewSP">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Device">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.FacilityName }" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Hardware}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind HostName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Device.cs

```
namespace RapidDeploy.Models
{
    public class Device
    {
        [Key]
        public int HostName { get; set; }
        public string DriveModel { get; set; }
        public string DriveSN { get; set; }
        public string OldDriveSN { get; set; }
        public bool Server { get; set; }
        public string RouterName { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
```

Location.cs

```
namespace RapidDeploy.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FacilityName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int BuildingNum { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
```

DisplayDeviceViewModel.cs

```
        private Device _ActiveDevice;
        private int _hostName;
        public int HostName { get { return _hostName; } set { Set(ref _hostName, value); } }
        var uriL = new Uri("http://localhost:2463/api/Locations/");
        var uriD = new Uri("http://localhost:2463/api/Devices/");


            var JsonResponseD = await client.GetStringAsync(uriD);
            var devicesResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Device>>(JsonResponseD);
            Devices = devicesResult;

            var JsonResponseL = await client.GetStringAsync(uriL);
            var locationsResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Location>>(JsonResponseL);
            Locations = locationsResult;
```

Comment: Add a common Interface to the clases and create a List<IYourInterface>. Maybe IListable is a name that tells about the purpose. A ToString is obviously helpful..

Comment: Or you can create `DeviceOrLocationViewModel` and use it. Imho binding straight to the models inside the view is not a great idea.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions.. Since I started, I have wanted to learn the clean most efficient way of applying MVVM methods. So, if there is a way to redirect the DataType to the ViewModel please share.

Comment: TaW, do you have a code sample or link that explains your suggestion?

Comment: Where is the Link between Location and Device?

Comment: I don't see any foreign key reference in either class does one exist?

Comment: I guess that is what I'm trying to get solved here... If in order to create a List, every item referenced in that list needs to be part of the same Class, then I'm going to have a problem. I need be able to display values from different Database Tables, (Classes) in the same ListView, if that requires me wiring up a handful of Foreign Keys to the Table/Class that has the most values then I need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create a new class and add those Members which you want to Bind in xaml. That means your DB Query will return the objects joining from many tables in a custom class like below :

MyBindedModel.cs

```
public class MyBindedModel
{
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    public string Hardware{ get; set; }
    public string HostName{ get; set; }
    //Many more depending on what you want to show on UI
}
```

Now in ViewModel you can use

```
public ObservableCollection<MyBindedModel> MyData
```

DisplayDevice.xaml

```
     <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyData}"
                      SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.deviceList_SelectionChanged}"
                       x:Name="deviceList" Margin="50,0,0,50"
                       Header="{x:Bind ViewModel.RouterName}"
                       RelativePanel.RightOf="EditViewSP">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="MyData">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FacilityName }" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Hardware}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind HostName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Well that would be helpful to add everything in the class that needs to be in each list I create. Next issue to think thru, is how to take the WebService JSON calls and split them out? I'm adding the code to the Original post for reference.

Comment: Because even thou I work with them in the App Mixed together, they still need to be Pulled, and Post to SQL as separate tables.

Comment: @ekgcorp you can always use Linq Projections to get the fields you want from a larger set.